# Tree and List on the same page

Tags: groovy, grails

Using Grails and the RichUI plugin to display a tree, and it works fine.
When I click one of the Nodes in the tree I show a list(table) from a controller.
I should be able to create new, edit and sort. 
My problem is that pagination doesn't work and also sorting!!!

Are there anyone who has done this, or can it be done differently ?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're getting your table data in an Ajax request. Check out the [remote-pagination](http://grails.org/plugin/remote-pagination) plugin. It has tags for paginate and sortableColumn that work with Ajax.